# Reduced QR factorization: Rank of A equals rank of $\hat{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix and let $A = \hat{Q} \hat{R}$ be the reduced QR factorization of $A$ such that $\hat{Q}$ is an $m \times n$ matrix with orthonormal columns and $\hat{R}$ is an an $n \times n$ matrix that is upper triangular.

Question: Is it true that rank$(A)$ = rank$(\hat{R})$? I know this to be true when $A$, $Q$ and $R$ are all square. Does this hold in the reduced $QR$ case though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Let $m \geq n$ and note that $\mathrm{rank}(\hat{Q}) = n$ since its columns are orthonormal. Thus $\mathrm{rank}(\hat{R}) = \mathrm{rank}(\hat{Q}\hat{R})$.

Comment: Can you explain that a little bit more please. I agree that $\hat{Q}$ has full rank, but how does that imply $\mathrm{rank}(\hat{R}) = \mathrm{rank}(\hat{Q}\hat{R})$.

Comment: Suppose $\mathrm{rank}(\hat{R}) = r$, then there $\hat{R}$ has $r$ linearly independent columns. Since each column of  $\hat{Q} \hat{R}$ is a linear combination wrt a particular column of $\hat{R}$, then only $r$ of these linear combinations (i.e. the columns of $\hat{Q} \hat{R}$) will themselves be linearly independent. Another view is that matrices which are full-rank do not "lose" information when they are multiplied. Here is a related page that might be of interest. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Properties